# How to get RGB color value from UISlider

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicolor

I have tried this code but not working properly.On value change of UISlider I called this method...

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *r;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *g;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *b;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *colorLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _r.minimumValue=0;
    _r.maximumValue=255;

    _g.minimumValue=0;
    _g.maximumValue=255;

    _b.minimumValue=0;
    _b.maximumValue=255;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)slider
{
    [_colorLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:_r.value green:_g.value blue:_b.value alpha:1]];
}
```

please help if any one have some idea..

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working properly". Is it displaying the wrong colour, is it not displaying any colour, is it not running the sliderValueChanged method, is it crashing your app, is your device exploding? There are many ways that something can "not work properly" saying this is absolutely no help whatsoever.

Comment: @Fogmeister i'm pretty sure it's the last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your setting color method as

```
-(void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)slider
{
    float r=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",_r.value] floatValue];
    float g=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",_g.value]floatValue];
    float b=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",_b.value]floatValue];

    UIColor *colorToSet=[UIColor colorWithRed:(r/255.0f) green:(g/255.0f) blue:(b/255.0f) alpha:1];
    [_colorLabel setBackgroundColor:colorToSet];
}
```

[Check Sample](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/4IbQYnl/0/blob?download)

Comment: Using sliders from 0 to 1 would save unnecessary calculations

Answer (score 4):

The `UIColor` methods take each component parameter in the range `0 to 1`, so you need to divide your slider values by `255.0` before passing them.

Comment: Or he could use sliders going just from 0 to 1 to avoid having to do that, as i did in my example

Answer (score 3):

Try this (Ignore the alpha slider, this is my own actual solution to a similar task) :

KEEP IN MIND : let your sliders go from 0 to 1 to avoid the division through 255.

.h file :

```
IBOutlet UISlider *rSlider;
IBOutlet UISlider *gSlider;
IBOutlet UISlider *bSlider;
```

.m file

```
-(void)blueSlider:(id)sender
{
    bSlider = (UISlider *)sender;
    UIColor *newColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:rSlider.value green:gSlider.value blue:bSlider.value alpha:alphaSlider.value];
    colorView.backgroundColor = newColor;
}



-(void)greenSlider:(id)sender
{
    gSlider = (UISlider *)sender;
    UIColor *newColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:rSlider.value green:gSlider.value blue:bSlider.value alpha:alphaSlider.value];
    colorView.backgroundColor = newColor;
}


-(void)redSlider:(id)sender
{
    rSlider = (UISlider *)sender;
    UIColor *newColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:rSlider.value green:gSlider.value blue:bSlider.value alpha:alphaSlider.value];
    colorView.backgroundColor = newColor;
}
```

Comment: The UIColor method accepts any value between 0 and 1 for each value (red, green, blue, alpha). Multiplying the values by 255 and printing them to a textfield should give you an idea of the slider#s accuracy

Comment: You should seriously consider extracting the common code into a separate method called from all three handlers.

Comment: @Exothug don't mind my statements.I only mean for that statement that u should optimize it by removing rest of two codes and call single method by three sliders and also u do not need this statement rSlider = (UISlider *)sender;

Answer (score 0):

For u  Exothug

If slider value from 0 to 1 only

```
-(IBAction)sliderValue:(UISlider*)sender
{
    UIColor *newColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:rSlider.value green:gSlider.value blue:bSlider.value alpha:1];
    _colorLabel.backgroundColor = newColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- First create 3 sliders in your Main.storyboard
- Second create all sliders action
       ex:. Red_slider, Green_slider, Blue_slider
- Third create 3 Labels and it's Outlets

---

Now in ViewCotroller

[Enter code in ViewController.swift same as like Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ454.png)

Comment: Please don't post codes as an image. Instead always post your code as code-formatted text, as explained in the site's help center docs.